# Emacs via X: how to use higher resolution fonts?

Tags: fonts, debian, x-window

I have attached a screenshot of Emacs 24.5 running in X-Quartz in a Debian VM.  Does anyone know how to configure Emacs to use higher resolution fonts?  For instance, like the ones Mac Terminal.app is using in the same screenshot?

Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToniS.png)

```
 $ dpkg -l|grep emacs
ii  emacs24                               24.5+1-11+deb9u1                            amd64        GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ GUI support)
ii  emacs24-bin-common                    24.5+1-11+deb9u1                            amd64        GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent files
ii  emacs24-common                        24.5+1-11+deb9u1                            all          GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture independent infrastructure
ii  emacs24-el                            24.5+1-11+deb9u1                            all          GNU Emacs LISP (.el) files
ii  emacs25                               25.1+1-4+deb9u1                             amd64        GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ GUI support)
ii  emacs25-bin-common                    25.1+1-4+deb9u1                             amd64        GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent files
ii  emacs25-common                        25.1+1-4+deb9u1                             all          GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture independent infrastructure
ii  emacs25-el                            25.1+1-4+deb9u1                             all          GNU Emacs LISP (.el) files
ii  emacsen-common                        2.0.8                                       all          Common facilities for all emacsen
```